# How can I increase the allowed size of HTTP GET requests on dotcloud?

Tags: perl, http-request, dotcloud

I am doing some [JSONP](http://enwp.org/JSONP) calls which limit me to [HTTP GET](http://enwp.org/HTTP#Request_methods) as the method of talking to the server.  I seem to be hitting an 8k limit on the size of the request.  I have tried changing my `dotcloud.yml` to

```
www:
  type: perl
  approot: webapp
  config:
    uwsgi_buffer_size: 65536
```

And created an `nginx.conf` file in the root of my project (the same level as the `dotcloud.yml`) that says

```
large_client_header_buffers 4 64k
```

But I am still hitting the 8k barrier.

Comment: Is it not possible to split the requests?

Comment: The limit may be related to the uWSGI buffer size, which is set to 8KB by default.  Look at dotCloud's updated documentation here: http://docs.dotcloud.com/services/perl/#custom-uwsgi-configuration to see how to override that default.  You'll have to destroy, create, and push again to ensure that the new settings get built into the platform.

Comment: @DavidO, please note the config section in the dotcould.yml I put in the question.  If you think I made a mistake in it, please post an answer.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid It is and I have done it, but it leads to some ugly code, so now that I have multiple request working I am trying to get a single request working.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently I was an idiot.  The nginx.conf file needs to go in the service's approot directory (in this case `./webapp` not `./`).  This makes perfect sense since you can have more than one service and you should be able to set the options for them individually.

Now I am hitting a 32k limit in my testing (but asked for 64k).  This is puzzling, but I don't really care enough to keep searching right now since 32k should be enough for a while.